# Retrieving Email Using PHP

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, cron

I know that this would be fairly easy id if I had a dedicated server.

Issues:
My hosting does not allow me to utilize the IMAP PHP extension.

I would like to find a small solution but the only thing im currently aware of as a solution is the Zend Framework.

What options do I have with the limitation of Imap extensions being disallowed.

Note: I'm looking to constantly check for new mail so I dont think POP3 would work well here.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~djkernen/Mail-IMAPClient/IMAPClient.pod

Comment: ahhh if i only felt comfortable in Perl

Comment: I'm presuming that you can't setup an SMTP server on your setup anywhere and send the email over HTTP to your PHP app? Alternatively you could use a third party like http://cloudmailin.com to send the emails to the PHP app without having to install anything to collect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the best solution for my hosting with go daddy was indeed the Zend framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have some links which may help you :

- https://github.com/AJenbo/PHP-imap
- http://wiki.horde.org/Project/HordeImapLib